# R Shiny: Getting Dynamic user input and making it a vector for a function

Tags: r, shiny

I am incredibly new to r, so this may be a simple fix. My problem is that I am trying to get 14 different integer inputs from the user, create a vector from those inputs, and pass that vector to a function. My hope is that I can do this dynamically.

Here is my code:

```
# Function
sonnet_print_vector <- function(user_vector){
    sonnet_list <- NULL
    for (i in seq_along(user_vector)){
        next_line <- filter(sonnets, sonnet==user_vector[i], line==i) %>%
            select(text)
        sonnet_list <- bind_rows(sonnet_list, next_line)
    }
    print(sonnet_list)
}

# Shiny script
ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("row1", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 1?", 1),
    numericInput("row2", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 2?", 1), 
    numericInput("row3", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 3?", 1), 
    numericInput("row4", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 4?", 1), 
    numericInput("row6", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 6?", 1), 
    numericInput("row5", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 5?", 1), 
    numericInput("row7", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 7?", 1), 
    numericInput("row8", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 8?", 1), 
    numericInput("row9", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 9?", 1), 
    numericInput("row10", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 10?", 1), 
    numericInput("row11", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 11?", 1), 
    numericInput("row12", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 12?", 1), 
    numericInput("row13", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 13?", 1), 
    numericInput("row14", "Which sonnet would you like displayed for row 14?", 1), 
    custom_sonnet <- c(row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10, row11, row12, row13, row14),
    verbatimTextOutput("q")
)

server <- function(input, output){
    output$q <- renderText({
        paste("Printing custom sonnet", input$custom_sonnet, "here:\n\n")
        paste(sonnet_print_vector(input$custom_sonnet), "\n")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It is quite clunky, so I am sorry about that. I have been using shiny for one hour, so I am probably missing something simple.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use one input and then depending on the input a user gives display the target sonnet? I can think of using a `selectInput` for instance and on server side display whatever is selected?

Comment: @NelsonGon I tried that, but I have a dataframe of 10 different sonnets, and I want the user to be able to select lines from one of the 10 different sonnets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have no idea what's in your dataframe and how the df will look like after your function, so I created a fake df with 10 rows. I imagined each row will just be some text of sonnets, so I use "sonnet 1-10".

The function I wrote is very simple too, just return you the `user_vector`. You may add your own stuff below `# do something` and change the return.

Then we can create your 14 inputs and get the values in following way:

```r
library(shiny)
sonnet <- data.frame(rows = paste0("sonnet", 1:10))

# function
myfunc <- function(user_vector){
    user_vector <- as.numeric(unlist(reactiveValuesToList(user_vector)))
    # do something
    
    user_vector
}


ui <- fluidPage(
    column(6,
       lapply(1:14, function(i){
           numericInput(
               paste0("row", i), 
               paste0("Which sonnet would you like displayed for row ", i, "?"), 
               value = 1, min = 1, max = nrow(sonnet)
           )
       })    
    ),    
    column(6,
        verbatimTextOutput("q")    
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    user_vector <- reactiveValues()
    lapply(paste0("row", 1:14), function(x) {
      observeEvent(input[[x]], {
          user_vector[[x]] <- input[[x]]
      })  
    })
    output$q <- renderPrint({
        cat("Printing custom sonnet\n")
        cat(sonnet$rows[myfunc(user_vector)], sep = "\n")
        cat("user vector is: ", myfunc(user_vector), "\n")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Try to change the user input and watch how your sonnet lines change.

[image]